# Managing caches within your android application

Tags: android, memory, memcached

I am new to android and I was wondering what the correct way is to manage and set some maximum limit for your application's data storage.  For instance,  I have an image cache and a database file with some information.  I do not want it to potentially become extremely big.  Is there a built in a way that android provides so I can manage the size of how much data is stored? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. You will have to manually do that. Your image cache would have a database and a cache folder. So, there is no custom method or class that you could use to set limits to the DB or the folder.

Comment: I see. So you dont know of anyway i can delete all of the cached memory in the application programmatically?

Comment: Well, you could delete the contents of your cache folder by using s simple delete call on the folder, and for the DB, a simple, delete statement would remove all the records. But, I would suggest to remove the cache incrementally, perhaps based on the last access timestamp of the resource.